# C# SslStream throws "Verification failure during handshake"

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to establish a simple TLS-connection between a server and a client in Unity with C#'s [SslStream-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream). Currently, both client and server run on my machine and the `hostIpAddress` and `serverName` are set to "127.0.0.1". I created a (self-signed) certificate file with OpenSSL and saved it under `pathToCertificate`.

The certificate file is being read without issues and the server can be opened, but when a client tries connecting, an AuthentificationException (Outer: "Authentication failed, see inner exception.", Inner: "Verification failure during handshake") is thrown in `sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(hostCertificate, false, true);`.

#### Server:

```cs
    hostCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToCertificate, "pw");
    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener.Start();
    
    TcpClient tcpConnection = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    
    // A client has connected. Create the
    // SslStream using the client's network stream.
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpConnection.GetStream(), false);
    
    // Authenticate the server but don't require the client to authenticate.
    try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(hostCertificate, false, true);
    
        // Set timeouts for the read and write to 2 seconds.
        sslStream.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        sslStream.WriteTimeout = 2000;
    }
    catch(AuthenticationException exc)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Exception during HostController Network Authentification:");
        Debug.LogError(exc.Message);
        if(exc.InnerException != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(exc.InnerException.Message);
        }
    
        tcpConnection.Close();
        sslStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

#### Client:

```cs
public ClientController()
{
    TcpClient tcpConnection = new TcpClient(hostIpAddress, port);
    
    // Create an SSL stream that will enclose the client's stream.
    hostStream = new SslStream(tcpConnection.GetStream(), false,
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate));
    // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
    try
    {
        hostStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
    }
    catch(AuthenticationException exc)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Exception during ClientController Network Authentification:");
        Debug.LogError(exc.Message);
        if(exc.InnerException != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(exc.InnerException.Message);
        }
    
        tcpConnection.Close();
        hostStream.Close();
    }
}

// The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
    public bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if(sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        Debug.LogError("Certificate error: " + sslPolicyErrors);

        // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
        return false;
    }
```

#### OpenSSL-Commands to create Certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out LocalCA.key 2048

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key LocalCA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out LocalCA.crt -config localhost.cnf -extensions v3_ca -subj "/CN=SocketTools LocalCA"

openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048

openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out localhost.csr -config localhost.cnf -extensions v3_req

openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA LocalCA.crt -CAkey LocalCA.key -CAcreateserial -out localhost.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -extfile localhost.cnf -extensions v3_req

openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt -certfile LocalCA.crt -password pass:pw
```

#### localhost.cnf:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
default_md = sha256
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_ca
req_extensions = v3_req
 
[req_distinguished_name]
C = AT
ST = Vienna
L = Vienna
O = FluffyVoxels
CN = localhost
 
[v3_ca]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
 
[v3_req]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
basicConstraints = critical, CA:false
nsCertType = server
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
 
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = 192.168.0.4
IP.3 = 2a02:8388:8a03:ac80:c8d6:6a1d:f2b0:c17d
IP.4 = ::1
```

[Wireshark Output during Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiF9b.png)

Comment: What is the code for `ValidateServerCertificate`

Comment: I updated the Client Code

Comment: A self-signed certificate will have `RemoteCertificateChainErrors.SslPolicyErrors` and in your case will also have `SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`. So `if(sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)` is going to be false, so will jump to `return false;`. If you want to ignore certificate errors you need to `return true;` in all cases

Comment: Didn't help, the error persists.

Comment: @kruemelkeksfan did you end up solving this issue? I have the exact same exception, with roughly the same code. Would appreciate it if you know the solution.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make this work:

If you use a client certificate, can simply be a self-signed one you supply with the client application, then the handshake does go well. I have now also successfully got it working with a LetsEncrypt cert on the server and a self-signed one on the client.

Tested with Unity 2021.3.7f1, both in 2 editors and with the server running on Ubuntu Linux as a Unity Dedicated Server build.

1. Generate a self-signed pfx cert:

   - Create private key:

     `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`
   - Create certifcate signing request (csr)

     `openssl req -new -sha256 -key key.pem -out csr.csr`
   - Create certificate

     `openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key key.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem`
   - Convert to .pfx file

     `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -out certificate.pfx`

   Note the password you set on the pfx file, to use in your C# code.
2. Change the code for creating the `SslStream` and for `AuthenticateAsClient` and `AuthenticateAsServer` and include a `LocalCertificateSelectionCallback`.

   Here is an example of what I got working:

   *(Specifically for Unity this example also includes storing the certificates in a TextAsset (just name it like `certificate.pfx.txt`), using a Coroutine to start the client, and using async on the server side so it doesn't block)*

   ##### Server side

   ```cs
   [SerializeField] int serverPort = 4578;
   [SerializeField] TextAsset certificateFile;

   void RunServer()
   {
       X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = new(certificateFile.bytes, "password");
       TcpListener listener = new(IPAddress.Any, serverPort);
       listener.Start();
       listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), listener);
   }

   private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   {
       TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
       TcpClient tcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
       ProcessClient(tcpClient);

       listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), listener);
   }

   void ProcessClient(TcpClient tcpClient)
   {
      ClientConnection client = new() { tcpClient = tcpClient };

       // A client has connected. Create the
       // SslStream using the client's network stream.
       client.stream = new(
           client.tcpClient.GetStream(),
           false,
           new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate),
           new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(CertificateSelectionCallback)
           );
       try
       {
           client.stream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, true, false);

           client.stream.BeginRead(client.buffer, 0, ClientConnection.BUFFER_SIZE,
               new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), client);
       }
       catch (AuthenticationException e)
       {
           Debug.LogException(e);
           if (e.InnerException != null)
           {
               Debug.LogError($"Inner exception: {e.InnerException.Message}");
           }
           Debug.LogWarning("Authentication failed - closing connection");
           client.stream.Close();
           tcpClient.Close();
           return;
       }
   }

   bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(
         object sender,
         X509Certificate certificate,
         X509Chain chain,
         SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
   {
       // Allow any client certificate
       return true;
   }

   X509Certificate CertificateSelectionCallback(object sender, string targetHost, X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, X509Certificate remoteCertificate, string[] acceptableIssuers)
   {
       return localCertificates[0];
   }
   ```

   State object class for async:

   ```cs
   public class ClientConnection
   {
       internal TcpClient tcpClient = null;
       internal SslStream stream = null;

       // These are used for reading from the stream async
       internal const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
       internal byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
       internal StringBuilder stringBuffer = new();
   }
   ```

   ##### Client side

   ```cs
   [SerializeField] string serverAddress;
   [SerializeField] TextAsset clientCertificate;
   TcpClient tcpClient;
   SslStream stream;

   void RunClient()
   {
       StartCoroutine(nameof(RunClientCoroutine));
   }

   IEnumerator RunClientCoroutine()
   {
       yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

       // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
       // machineName is the host running the server application.
       tcpClient = new(serverAddress, serverPort);

       // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
       stream = new(
           client.tcpClient.GetStream(),
           false,
           new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(CertificateSelectionCallback)
           );
       // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
       try
       {
           bool authenticationPassed = true;
           X509Certificate2 cert = new(clientCertificate.bytes, "password");
           X509Certificate2Collection certs = new();
           certs.Add(cert);
           stream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverAddress, certs, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
           authenticationPassed = client.stream.IsAuthenticated;

           if(authenticationPassed) StartClient();
       }
       catch (AuthenticationException e)
       {
           Debug.LogException(e);
           if (e.InnerException != null)
           {
               Debug.LogError($"Inner exception: {e.InnerException.Message}");
           }
           Debug.LogWarning("Authentication failed - closing connection");
           tcpClient.Close();
       }
   }

   // The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
   bool ValidateServerCertificate(
       object sender,
       X509Certificate certificate,
       X509Chain chain,
       SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
   {
       if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
           return true;

   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch && (serverAddress == "localhost" || serverAddress == "127.0.0.1" || serverAddress == "::1"))
           return true;
   #endif

       Debug.LogError($"Certificate error: {sslPolicyErrors}");

       // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
       return false;
   }

   X509Certificate CertificateSelectionCallback(object sender, string targetHost, X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, X509Certificate remoteCertificate, string[] acceptableIssuers)
   {
       return localCertificates[0];
   }
   ```

For production, to convert a LetsEncrypt cert already running on a unix server from certbot apache to a pfx file for C# X509, it would be something like this:

`sudo openssl pkcs12 -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem -export -out unitykey.pfx`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a Unity Bug here (calling VerifyCertificate() with null and throwing an exception when null is not recognized as a valid certificate):

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/06e6ccece853a5373a6545a821ca178f4ec57f20/mcs/class/System/Mono.UnityTls/UnityTlsContext.cs#L344

Comment: You are mistaking UnityTls for .Net SslStream that you used above. This bug is not relevant to the question you asked, as you're not using UnityTls there.

Comment: As far as I remember, this is a Unity Library, because Unity does reimplement .Net Libraries by itself. You can not use vanilla .Net in Unity. Could be wrong though, my memories about this are very vague.

Comment: Your solution also indicates that it is indeed this piece of code, which is causing trouble. I remember that issuing client certificates would likely have solved the problem, but I had no idea how to issue client certificates on end user machines, so I scrapped this idea.